# Cambiar valor de un campo de Select en base a otra tabla

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

La situacion que presento no se explicarla bien.

Pero tengo una tabla de partidos con los siguientes campos: `Identificador`, `tipo de deporte`, `fecha`, `visitante` y `local`.

Visitante y local son de tipo `int`.

Al momento de realizar un select queda algo asi:

```
1 | 1 | 01-01-1900 | 1 | 2
```

Tengo otra tabla de equipos con los siguientes campos: `Identificador`, `nombre` y `tipo de deporte`.

Me gustaria poder remplazar el identificador del equipo visitante y local con el nombre que se encuentra en la tabla de equipos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu query se puede solucionar usando subquerys para los campos para los cuales quieres el detalle:

```
select Identificador, 
       tipo de deporte, 
       fecha, 
       (select nombre from equipos where p.visitante = e.identificador) as visitante,
       (select nombre from equipos where p.local= e.identificador) as local 
from partidos p
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo, la respuesta me sirvio completamente.